# Как написать php-функцию, чтобы связать картинку с записью WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Добрый день, уважаемые участники форума. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Объясню ситуацию:
В файле content.php у меня есть такой код:

```html
<a class="postThumb" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true); ?>" />
</a>
```

Этот код нужен для вывода миниатюры записи на главной странице. Сейчас, чтобы привязать картинку к записи и вывести ее миниатюру я добавляю для каждой записи новое [произвольное поле](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) с названием thumbnail и значением = URL-адрес первой картинки записи. Как бы мне автоматизировать этот процесс?

Я предполагаю так: добавить в functions.php код, чтобы для всех записей добавилось произвольное поле thumbnail и в него подставлялось бы адрес картинки, который содержится в посте. Есть ли готовое решение для этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании/редактировании поста ему можно задать изображение. Функцию для вывода как таковую писать не надо, так как она уже есть - get_the_post_thumbnail(). Ваши миниатюры на главной страницы выводятся (предполагаю) через цикл `while`, вот в этот цикл, в шаблон миниатюры, вместо

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true); ?>" />
```

вам и надо вставить

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

Про саму функцию и то, что ей надо/можно передавать, можно посмотреть [тут](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/)

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать более развернутый ответ?

Comment: @br3t обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте поддержку миниатюр к вашей теме. в `functions.php` добавляем следующий код:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

и все будет работать, как задумано.

В ответ на коммент:

Полное описание функции - https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_theme_support

Для того, чтобы вывести миниатюру записи на странице, используем следующий код:

```
<php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} ?>
```

Comment: 1. Все готовые темы поддерживают миниатюры, разве что ТС пишет свою тему, что вряд ли. 2. Этот код работать не будет, его надо добавлять иначе. 3. Даже если добавить правильно, код в вопросе работать не будет, WP использует мета` _thumbnail_id`, получив который, надо еще само изображение как attachment вытащить.